# Type erasure unexpected behavior in Java

Tags: java, generics

According to Java's documentation on [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), I understand that in the code example below both versions of `doStuff()` will have the same erasure and, therefore, won't compile. My goal is to **overload `doStuff()` in order to receive collections of `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`**.

```
import java.util.List;

class Example {
  class ClassOne {
  }

  class ClassTwo {
  }

  public void doStuff(List<ClassOne> collection) {
  }

  public void doStuff(List<ClassTwo> collection) {
  }
}
```

Mechanics for type erasure include the following step:

> · Replace all type parameters in generic types **with their bounds** or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Therefore, I should be able to apply a bound and then it would compile because now the type erased version of doStuff is overloaded with two different signatures (the declared upper bounds). Example:

```
class Example {
  class ClassOne {
  }

  class ClassTwo {
  }

  public <U extends ClassOne> void doStuff(List<U> collection) {
  }

  public <U extends ClassTwo> void doStuff(List<U> collection) {
  }
}
```

This second example actually doesn't compile and gives the following error:

> Error:(15, 36) java: name clash: doStuff(java.util.List) and doStuff(java.util.List) have the same erasure

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Well, you specified an unbounded parameter `U` and you got two methods that both resolved to `doStuff(List<Object>)`, just as the documentation said.

Comment: if method with List<ClassOne> did not work , why did you expect that adding 'extends' will change smth?

Comment: Because when you write `extends` or `super` then the type parameter becomes bounded and I though that could represent a loophole to my type erasure problem (according to the linked documentation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `List<U>` will be reduced to just `List` in both your methods. (You can't have `List<ClassOne>` or `List<Object>` left after erasure.)

The passage you quote means that it is ok to have the following declaration:

```
class Example {
    class ClassOne {
    }

    class ClassTwo {
    }

    public <U extends ClassOne> void doStuff(U foo) {
    }

    public <U extends ClassTwo> void doStuff(U foo) {
    }
}
```

Here the generic arguments will be replaced by `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` respectively, which works just fine.

Comment: Simple and concise explanation. +1

Comment: And could one write doStuff in order to somehow receive a List<>? Or is is forbidden by type erasure mechanics?

Comment: No, unfortunately overloading doesn't work when the argument only differs by type parameter.